# Tengo un problema a la hora de crear un nuevo proyecto de angular

Tags: angular

Hola ¿como estan? espero que muy bien, queria compartir con ustedes una inquietud que tengo; recientemente me pidieron que estudiara angular y pues, he tenido problemas a la hora de crear un nuevo proyecto y no tengo muchas ideas de que pueda estarlo ocasionando, ya instale y desinstale angular/cli, nodejs, npm. Y sigo sin conseguir una solución.

Cuando intento crear un nuevo proyecto, se queda cargando en el archivo "My-app/src/app/app.component<.scss/.css/en su defecto>", luego de un rato no carga y me dice "The Schematic workflow failed. See above".

de ante mano muchisímas gracias.

Nota: Estoy usando Nodejs 12.20 x64bits y npm 8.2.0

Comment: Actualiza tu versión de node a la 16, que ahora es la estable. Aunque ancular cli puede trabajar con tu versión de node, es recomendable usar la lts. (Long term support)

Comment: Muchas gracias, el asunto es que trabajo con windows 7 64bits, ya que mi pc pues no es muy buena, y al intentar instalar nodejs 16, me dice que no es posible, que se requiere Windows 8.1 mínimo para instalar esa versión. Igual muchísimas gracias. Ya lo he solucionado.

Comment: Excelente. Publica tu respuesta para cerrar la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

> Busca en el vinculo la compatibilidad entre Node,Angular,Typescript
> para mayor seguridad desinstala nuevamente y verifica la vercion de
> tsc -v la cual tambien podes desinatalar O dejar de acuerdo a la configuración que vayas a utilizar

1.npm cache clean --force

> 2. Desde Windows desinstalar o cambiar programa (Desinstalar node)

3.Ver compatibilidad-->[Ver compatibilidad entre Angular,Node Typescript-->](https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3)

> 4.npm install -g node@version......luego

npm cache clean --force

npm uninstall –g @angular/CLI

> npm i -g @angular/cli@x.y.z